# Error!!! NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm getting these issues:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
System.out.println("Amount of elements to calculate: ");
try
{
   x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
}
catch(NumberFormatException | IOException z)
{
   System.out.println("Error!!!"+z);
}

int [] n = new int[x];
```

this is how I'm reading the values of the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++)
    n[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

this is how I call the method and send the array as a parameter

```
obj.asignar(n);
```

and this is the method in my class in which I load the array:

```
private int[] num;

public void asignar(int n[])
{

    for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++)
    {
        num[i] = n[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the exception and its error message? What do you think `For input string: ""` means? If your problem is with input, please include that input and all relevant code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "" is not integer . If you try to parse it it will give the mentions exception. Check before parsing or have appropriate exception handling

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException or a NumberFormatException? Those are different.

Comment: Try the below               try{    int i = Integer.parseInt(yourinput); }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception    ... }

Comment: @cricket_007 A `NumberFormatException` from the `parseInt`, then a `NullPointerException` presumably from `x` being `null` and used in `new int[x]`.

Comment: I get both I wrote. When I run the code and for example i type 3 as the amount of elements it only lets me introduce 2 , then I get the error , and I only type integers, no string

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get an integer from an **empty** `String`:

```
Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());   // when br.readLine() is ""
```

but you can use 2 common approaches:

1. **Skip** the **empty** `String`s:

   ```
   String line = br.readLine();
   if ( !"".equals(line)) {
       x = Integer.parseInt(line);
   }
   ```
2. Use a **default value** for the empty String - like `0`:

   ```
   String line = br.readLine();
   x = "".equals(line) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line);
   ```

   You can also generalize this approach by writing a new method:

   ```
   static int parseInt(String s, int defaultValue) {
       try {
           return Integer.parseInt(s);
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           return defaultValue;
       }
   }
   ```

   that can be called using:

   ```
   x = parseInt(br.readLine(), 0);
   ```

---

Related to your comment, it's easy to read as many elements as you want. Just define a `total` and use it in a `for` loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int total = 3;
    int n[] = new int[total];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        n[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // use the approaches above
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
}
```

E.g.:

If your input is

```
1
2
3
```

the output will be

```
[1, 2, 3]
```